# How to select the input with jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to get the value of a input and i want to do it with jquery.

I just want to get the value of the hidden input with `name="picture"`***when*** I click on `حذف این بخش` button which have `onclick="deleteDefaultSection($(this))`.
I have used `.parent()` function to come out of that scope. But when I'm in the div with `class="ribbon-wrapper card"`. I cant go into the div with `class="col-md-12"` and select the value of hidden input with `class="picture"` in it.

```html
<div class="ribbon-wrapper card">
  <div class="card-header">
    <div class="ribbon ribbon-default pull-right">
      <input type="text" style="height: 24px;
      border-radius: 3px;
      border: none;
      padding: 5px;
      font-size: 12px;
      width: 130px;
      text-align: center;
      font-weight: normal;" name="name" class="nameSection" placeholder="بازه زمانی را وارد کنید" value="<%= analysis.timeFrames[i] %>" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <div style="float: right;
    top: 15px;
    right: 20px;">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AddSection" data-type="">اضافه
                                                    کردن عکس
                                                </button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger" onclick="deleteDefaultSection($(this))">حذف این بخش
                                                </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- This row is for showing the uploaded image and its description -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12" style="text-align: center;">
      <input type="hidden" class="picture" name="picture" value="<%= analysis.images[i] %>">
      <input type="hidden" class="details" name="details" value="<%= analysis.imagesDesc[i] %>">
      <input type="hidden" class="sectionname" name="timeFrames" value="<%= analysis.timeFrames[i] %>">
      <div class="boxUploadImage Active" data-typeSection="<%= i %>" data-name="<%= i + 64 %>">
        <img onclick="viewPicture($(this))" src="<%= analysis.images[i] %>" width="80%" height="200px">
        <div data-toggle="modal" data-target="#viewDiscription" onclick="viewDetails($(this))" class="p ">
          <%= analysis.imagesDesc[i] %>
        </div>
        <div class="boxBotton row my-5">
          <div class="col-lg-7 mr-4">
            <button class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-twitter" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#EditSection" onclick="editSection($(this), event)">ویرایش</button>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4">
            <button class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-danger deleteSection" onclick="deleteSection($(this))">حذف</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please make a [mcve] with proper RENDERED HTML and preferably English texts - why do you pass $(this) instead of `this` or better use addEventListener as you should

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
function deleteDefaultSection(obj) {
  var pic = obj.closest(".card").find('[name="picture"]');
  console.log(pic.val());
}
```

`.closest(".card")` travels up in the html and selects the first element with the class `card` it finds.

Then you can use `.find()` and combine it with `[name="picture"]` to get the element that has the `name` attribute with the value `picture` of it

**Demo**

```js
function deleteDefaultSection(obj) {
  var pic = obj.closest(".card").find('[name="picture"]');
  console.log(pic.val());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ribbon-wrapper card">
  <div class="card-header">
    <div class="ribbon ribbon-default pull-right">
      <input type="text" style="height: 24px;
                                                border-radius: 3px;
                                                border: none;
                                                padding: 5px;
                                                font-size: 12px;
                                                width: 130px;
                                                text-align: center;
                                                font-weight: normal;" name="name" class="nameSection" placeholder="بازه زمانی را وارد کنید" value="<%= analysis.timeFrames[i] %>" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <div style="float: right;
                                                top: 15px;
                                                right: 20px;">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AddSection" data-type="">اضافه
                                                    کردن عکس
                                                </button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger" onclick="deleteDefaultSection($(this))">حذف این بخش
                                                </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- This row is for showing the uploaded image and its description -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12" style="text-align: center;">
      <input type="hidden" class="picture" name="picture" value="Hiddenvalue">
      <input type="hidden" class="details" name="details" value="<%= analysis.imagesDesc[i] %>">
      <input type="hidden" class="sectionname" name="timeFrames" value="<%= analysis.timeFrames[i] %>">
      <div class="boxUploadImage Active" data-typeSection="<%= i %>" data-name="<%= i + 64 %>">
        <img onclick="viewPicture($(this))" src="<%= analysis.images[i] %>" width="80%" height="200px">
        <div data-toggle="modal" data-target="#viewDiscription" onclick="viewDetails($(this))" class="p ">
          <%= analysis.imagesDesc[i] %>
        </div>
        <div class="boxBotton row my-5">
          <div class="col-lg-7 mr-4">
            <button class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-twitter" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#EditSection" onclick="editSection($(this), event)">ویرایش</button>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4">
            <button class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-danger deleteSection" onclick="deleteSection($(this))">حذف</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh! I didn't realize the ```.closest()``` function like that. But as the way you used it. It Works!!! Thanks for answering.

Comment: @Efijoon No problem, happy to help :)